# Hodge dual with Levi-Civita symbol or tensor?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

In a curved spacetime with a general Minkowskian metric $g_{\mu\nu}$, I understand the difference between the Levi-Civita symbol $\pmb{\in}^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$ (which is a tensor-density of weight $W=+1$) with the reference $\pmb{\in}_{0123}=1$, and Levi-Civita tensor $$\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\pmb{\in}^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$$ with the reference $\varepsilon_{0123}=\sqrt{-g}$ and weight $W=0$. However, I don't understand which of them should I use in order to construct the Hodge dual. For example, consider the electromagnetic tensor
$$F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu,$$
then I have two options
$$F^{*\mu\nu}=\frac12 \pmb{\in}^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}F_{\rho\sigma}\tag{1} = \pmb{\in}^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial_\rho A_\sigma,\label{tag1}$$
$$H^{*\mu\nu}=\frac12 \varepsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}F_{\rho\sigma}\tag{2} = \varepsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\partial_\rho A_\sigma\label{tag2}.$$

I personally like option \eqref{tag1} because it implies
$$\partial_\nu F^{*\mu\nu} = 0, $$
and then automatically (because for any anti-symmetric tensor-density and torsion-free connection, one has $\partial_\nu F^{*\mu\nu} = \nabla_\nu F^{*\mu\nu}$) we have the covariant conservation law
$$\nabla_\nu F^{*\mu\nu} = 0.\tag{1a}$$
However, the second option \eqref{tag2} is used everywhere in the literature, which is not conserved in the ordinary sense:
$$\partial_\nu H^{*\mu\nu} =-H^{*\mu\nu}\Gamma^\lambda_{\ \nu\lambda},$$
but, nevertheless, it is conserved covariantly
$$\nabla_\nu H^{*\mu\nu} = 0.\tag{2a}$$

So, is there any controversy in using the Levi-Civita **symbol** $\pmb{\in}^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$ in constructing the Hodge dual instead of the conventionally used Levi-Civita **tensor** $\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$?

Comment: For one thing, your Hodge dual depends on the coordinates used.

Comment: You must use the Levi-Civita *tensor* if you want to have a proper tensor equation.

Comment: $\epsilon$ and $\varepsilon$ are a really bad choice for different variables because they look almost identical in some fonts, especially at small sizes. I had to look at the source of this post to see the symbols are supposed to be distinct.

Comment: More on [Levi-Civita symbol & tensor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=levi+civita+symbol+tensor+metric+density).

Comment: @mike stone,  I agree that in order to have Hodge dual being a proper tensor one has to use the standard definition with Levi-Civita tensor. However, the resulting PDEs are covariant in both cases, (1a) and (2a). And from this standpoint, I cannot see fundamental contradictions so far.

Comment: Isn't this just the matter of naming? The general convention is to call Hodge dual proper tensors. Then for example, you don't have worry about the metric determinants when going between differential forms (of Hodge duals) and their tensors.